# Price does not multiply by the input number given,

Tags: javascript, angular

[image: Screenshot 1]

It's meant to multiply the 1 by 5, as you can see but I don't know how, I've tried stuff with `ngModel` but that didn't work.

This is the code in the HTML of the input and what has to be the total price:

```html
<input type="number" style="width:40px; float:right;" />
<br>
<hr>
<p style="float: left;">Total price:</p>
<p style="float: right;"> <b>€{{activeProduct.price * inputNum}}</b>,-</p>
```

This is the model I made for the product:

[image]

This is the code in my TypeScript file:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tool-card',
  templateUrl: './tool-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tool-card.component.css']
})
export class ToolCardComponent implements OnInit {
  public activeProduct: any;
  public inputNum: number;

  products: Product[] = [
    new Product('Hammer', 'Hammer', 'Item used to hammer things', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Claw-hammer.jpg', 1),
    new Product('Saw', 'Hammer', 'I just saw a guy saying the n-word', 'https://media.screwfix.com/is/image//ae235?src=ae235/32045_P&$prodImageMedium$', 2),
    new Product('Hit or miss', 'Hit or miss', 'I guess they never miss huh, mwah', 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ds5mk0RU0AA1z_l.jpg', 5)
  ];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public calculateTotal() {
    this.activeProduct.price * this.inputNum;
  }

  public openModal(product): void {
    // Copying object reference so we don't modify the original
    this.activeProduct = Object.assign({}, product);
    this.inputNum = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `calculateTotal` does nothing - did you mean to use `return this.activeProduct.price * this.inputNum` or `this.activeProduct.price *= this.inputNum` perhaps?

Comment: Are you properly binding the inputted value to the inputNum variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not bound the input box to anything, use ngModel

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="inputNum" style="width:40px; float:right;" />
```

or if you don't want to use the forms module

```
<input type="number" (change)="inputNum = $event.target.value" style="width:40px; float:right;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you add FormsModule to your imports array in your `app.module.ts` file

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
    FormsModule
  ],
  ...etc
})
```

2. HTML File

```
<div>
   <p>{{ activeProduct.price }} </p>
   <label for="amount">Amount</label>
   <input type="number" (change)="calculateTotal() [(ngModel)]="activeProduct.numOfItems"/>
   <br>
   <hr>
   <p style="float: left;">Total price:</p>
   <p [(ngModel)]="totalCost">{{ totalCost }}</p>
</div>
```

3. ts file

```
export class AppComponent {
    activeProduct: any = {
        price: 12,
        name: 'pizza',
        numOfItems: 0
    };

    totalCost: number = 0;

    constructor() {}

    calculateTotal(): number {
        return this.totalCost = this.activeProduct.numOfItems * this.activeProduct.price;
    }
}
```

not the most elegant way but it will get you there. I think the biggest gotcha is FormsModule

Comment: you can write directly in .html: {{activeProduct.price*activeProduct.numOfItem}}, and the only [(ngModel)] you need is the activeProduct.numOfItems